# Passing datetime to json using python

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x

i am new to python programming 
i have a dictionary object like

```
data={
    'joiningdate': datetime.datetime(2016, 10, 13, 0, 0),
    'shift': datetime.time(8, 0)
}
```

i want to pass this value to json 
what i am done is

```
class MyEncoder1(json.JSONEncoder):
   def default(self, obj):
       if isinstance(obj,datetime.date):
           obj= datetime.datetime.strptime(obj,"%Y-%m-%d ")
       elif isinstance(obj, datetime.datetime):
           obj= datetime.datetime.strptime(obj,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
       elif isinstance(obj, datetime.time):
           obj = datetime.time.strftime(obj,"%H:%M:%S")
       elif isinstance(obj, Decimal):
           obj = float(obj)
       else:
           obj = super(MyEncoder1, self).default(obj)
       return obj
   json_array = dumps(data,cls=MyEncoder1)
```

it is printing time only like 00:08:00
but date is not printing 
can any one please help

Answer (score 0):

There are two mistakes here.

First, your encoder should return a serializable object so you should replace all calls to `strptime` with `strftime`. `strptime` constructs `datetime` objects from a string (so your code throws `TypeError`) and I guess you want the opposite.

Second, `datetime.datetime()` are in fact instances of `datetime.date`, so when your 'joiningdate' field is serialised, it enters the first if branch and that's it. It should work if you switch `if isinstance(obj,datetime.date)` and `elif isinstance(obj, datetime.datetime)`:

```
class MyEncoder1(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj, datetime.datetime):
            obj= datetime.datetime.strftime(obj,"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
        elif isinstance(obj,datetime.date):
            obj= datetime.datetime.strftime(obj,"%Y-%m-%d ")
        elif isinstance(obj, datetime.time):
            obj = datetime.time.strftime(obj,"%H:%M:%S")
        elif isinstance(obj, Decimal):
            obj = float(obj)
        else:
            obj = super(MyEncoder1, self).default(obj)
        return obj
```

Comment: i am printing the elements in the obj   it is giving only one obj : 08:00:00
json array: {"joiningdate": {"$date": 1476316800000}, "shift": "08:00:00"}
i am getting same output and the  value of date is not changed